# Custom rule for application/problem+json using Stoplight Spectral CLI

Tags: openapi, lint, spectral, stoplight

I'm trying to make a custom rule based on the *unkown-error-format* that can be found here [here](https://github.com/openapi-contrib/style-guides/blob/master/apisyouwonthate.yml). Using this Open API document as an example:

*openapi-generated.yaml*

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: API
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: https://api.com/
paths:
  /:
    get:
      tags: []
      summary: Your GET endpoint
      description: Your GET endpoint
      operationId: get-endpoint
      responses:
        "500":
          description: Error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                properties:
                  errorDescription:
                    type: string
```

and this rule set:

*.spectral.yml*

```yaml
extends:
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapi-contrib/style-guides/master/apisyouwonthate.yml

rules:
  unknown-error-format: error
```

When running

`spectral lint --ruleset .spectral.yml openapi-generated.yaml`

I was expecting an error to be returned, because the 500 response content is `application/json` and not one of the allowed values `application/vnd.api+json`, `application/problem+xml`, and `application/problem+json`.

Instead no errors are found:

`No results with a severity of 'error' or higher found!`

I experimented with some other [Spectral core functions](https://meta.stoplight.io/docs/spectral/ZG9jOjExNg-core-functions) that should make the linter return an error, but it does not. I suspect the expression in given is not returning the right result, internally.

Additionally, I tried using this [JSON Path Demo](http://jsonpath.com/) to check if the output array with "application/json" is returned for the path in the rule's given. It does.

Is there a problem with this rule or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Spectral version 6.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the clue to that?

Comment: I guess he managed to solve it somehow... :)